# Getting full path to a package source from the package import path

Tags: go, gopath, go-packages

Currently I have a parameter like `str := "github.com/pkg/errors"`. I need the full path to the package.

Currently how I achieve this is by using `build.Default.GOPATH+"/src/"+str`.

Is there a native non hacky way of resolving the full path to an import (which could be in a `vendor` folder etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [go/build](https://godoc.org/go/build) package to resolve an import path to a directory:

```
 p, err := build.Default.Import("github.com/pkg/errors", ".", build.FindOnly)
 if err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
 d := p.Dir
```

This snippet resolves [local imports](https://godoc.org/go/build#IsLocalImport) relative to the current working directory.  Replace `"."` with `""` if you don't want to resolve local imports or supply a different directory if appropriate.